# How to create a SAS Library Folder

Tags: data-science-model, sas

I am trying to create a folder to use in the SAS library. I have tried to do this many different ways. Every time I run the code it always says that the path does not exist.

Below is my error messages from my last attempt:

```
 72         
 73         libname "D:\Users\clkehl01\Documents\myprj1\";
 ERROR: "D:\Users\clkehl01\Documents\myprj1\" is not a valid SAS name.
 ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
 74         
 75         data myprj1.autos;
 76         set sashelp.cars;
 77         run;



 ERROR: Library MYPRJ1 does not exist.
 NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
```

Comment: Please consider editing your question to make it a little bit more clear. Just printing error codes sometimes makes it difficult to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

library name should be defined along with libname statement and its path. try below

libname myprj1 'D:\Users\clkehl01\Documents\myprj1\';

data myprj1.autos;
set sashelp.cars;
run;

Comment: Please consider improving this answer. This may include proper spelling, grammar, and code formatting.